# Can I create follow-up actions on Actions on Google?

Tags: actions-on-google

I know that I can deep link into my Google Home application by adding to my actions.json.

I also know that I can parse raw string values from the `app.StandardIntents.TEXT` intent that's provided by default, which I am currently doing like so:

```
if(app.getRawInput() === 'make payment') {
    app.ask('Enter payment information: ');
}
else if(app.getRawInput() === 'quit') {
    app.tell('Goodbye!');
}
```

But does Actions on Google provide direct support for creating follow-up intents, possibly after certain user voice inputs?

An example of a conversation flow is:

*OK Google, talk to my app.*

***Welcome to my app, I can order your most recent purchase or your saved favorite. Which would you prefer?***

*Recent purchase.*

***Should I use your preferred address and method of payment?***

*Yes.*

***OK, I've placed your order.***

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer won't work after testing.
Here is a tested version.

```js
exports.conversationComponent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const app = new ApiAiApp({request: req, response: res});
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  
  const registerCallback = (app, funcName)=>{
    if (!app.callbackMap.get(funcName)){
      console.error(`Function ${funcName} required to be in app.callbackMap before calling registerCallback`);
      return;
    }
    app.setContext("callback_followup", 1, {funcName});
  }

  const deRegisterCallback = (app)=>{
    const context = app.getContext("callback_followup");
    const funcName = app.getContextArgument("callback_followup", "funcName").value;
    const func = app.callbackMap.get(funcName);
    app.setContext("callback_followup", 0);
    return func;
  }

  app.callbackMap = new Map();
  app.callbackMap.set('endSurvey', (app)=>{
    if (app.getUserConfirmation()) {
      app.tell('Stopped, bye!');
    }
    else {
      app.tell('Lets continue.');
    }
  });

  app.callbackMap.set('confirmationStartSurvey', (app)=>{
    const context = app.getContext("callback_follwup");
    if (app.getUserConfirmation()) {
      registerCallback(app, 'endSurvey');
      app.askForConfirmation('Great! I\'m glad you want to do it!, do you want to stop?');
    } else {
      app.tell('That\'s okay. Let\'s not do it now.');
    }
  });

    



  // Welcome
  function welcome (app) {
    registerCallback(app, 'confirmationStartSurvey');
    const prompt = "You have one survey in your task list, do you want to proceed now?";
    app.askForConfirmation(prompt);
    
  }
 
  function confirmationCalbackFollowup (app) {
    const context = app.getContext("callback_followup");
    if (! context){
      console.error("ERROR: confirmationCallbackFollowup should always has context named callback_followup. ");
      return;
    }
    const callback = deRegisterCallback(app);
    return callback(app);
  }
  
  const actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(WELCOME, welcome);
  actionMap.set('confirmation.callback.followup', confirmationCalbackFollowup );  
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

The previous solution won't work because app is generated everytime the action function is called. I tried to save a callback function into app.data but it won't be existing next intent coming. So I changed another way. Register the callback function to app.callbackMap inside the function. so it will be there anyway.

To make it work, one important thing is Api.Ai need to have context defined in the intent. [See the Api.Ai Intent here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtnUf.png)

Make sure you have event, context, and action of course. otherwise, this intent won't be triggered.

Please let me know if you can use this solution. sorry for my previous wrong solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of a conversation flow that has what you are trying to do?

If you can use API.AI, they have [Follow Up intents in the docs](https://api.ai/docs/intents#follow-up_intents).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your code

```
if(app.getRawInput() === 'make payment') {
    app.ask('Enter payment information: ');
}
else if(app.getRawInput() === 'quit') {
    app.tell('Goodbye!');
}
```

is a good idea. I would suggest you have two different intent to handle "Payment information" and "Quit".

Comment: I agree with you, but is there any way to make follow-up intents (i.e. chainable intents)? So far I only know how to make separate intents which are all entry-points into the application.